# What is the most suitable HTML5 element to be used for "clear: both;" purposes?

Tags: html, css

I have:

```
<section>
    <ul>
        <li>....</li>
        <li>....</li>
        <li>....</li>
        ..
    </ul>
</section>
```

I want the `<li>` to be floating left and at the end of of these `<li>`, right after the `</ul>`, I need to put an element as `clear: both;` in order to keep `section`s block integrity.

Which html5 element would be most suitable for this purpose?
Should I go for an invisible `hr`? a `div`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**None**, use the `overflow: hidden` trick where appropriate.

If that isn't suitable, use a pseudo element. For example, you could use...

```
ul:after { 
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hello, what is the overflow: hidden tick?

Comment: By specifying overflow: hidden; (actually I'd suggest starting with auto and using hidden only if necessary) you force a height calculation a side effect of which is containment of floating children.

Comment: @reisio `auto` gets ugly when elements *do* overflow, however :)

Comment: It does, but not as ugly as people do when they aren't aware of how many random extra margins and paddings they have because everything is set to overflow: hidden;. :)  I usually start with auto except for nav areas.

Comment: Hello again. I am confused. Which one should I employ? Overflow hidden, auto or the 3 line wunder code? They all seem to work.

Comment: @Phil I use `overflow: hidden` (or `overflow: auto`) where I can because it's the simplest. It's only CSS property and implemented in the shitty IEs.

Comment: @alex If you saw that tag's of OP then it's good to use second method because is not hide the overflow content :)

Comment: @Phil: use this answer's approaches, tried in the order given, as appropriate. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) method for this. Write like this:

```
ul:after{
 content:'';
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Using the :after and those 3 lines of code seems to work. Do I still employ what's written on the .clearfix page? Thank you.

Comment: Those three line also work :). There no need to use those lines

Comment: Who give me downvote is good if he explain where is i am wrong thanks :)

Comment: You aren't wrong, the other answer is simply better. Nothing personal. :)

Comment: If other anwser is simply better you give a DOWNVOTE to an other. That not a good reason

Comment: I find it in accordance with http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down — specifically, I found your answer the "least useful".  Again, it's nothing personal.

Comment: @reisio - To the quesion "When should I vote down", the answer is ".. whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." Neither of those situations apply here.

Comment: Indeed they don't, but "Voting down…indicates which…answers are least useful." does. It's not my fault they aren't perfectly specific.

Comment: @reisio There are some your answers which are not be an answer which would be a comment like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920493/how-can-i-stretch-background-on-the-whole-window/5920538#5920538 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952993/applying-drop-shadows-to-divs/2953355#2953355 . But some people also give an upvote on that. Reason your answer is not so good but may be it's helpful for them or for future searchers. We give upvote as an appreciation that your answer is helpful.

Comment: I have little control over the behavior of others, only my own.